# Can aluminium hydroxide be split into Al 3+ and OH-?

Tags: aqueous-solution

When writing a net ionic equation containing aluminum hydroxide, can the aluminum hydroxide be split into ions of $\ce{Al^3+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$, or does it stay as $\ce{Al(OH)3}$?

Comment: When you deal with soluble compounds, you may write them either way as you see fit. But when a compound is insoluble, leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Aluminum hydroxide has poor solubility in water (solubility product $3 \times 10^{-34}$).

However, $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ is amphoteric and soluble in acids and bases. An excess of $\ce{OH-}$ will form tetrahydroxidoaluminate:

$\ce{Al(OH)3 + OH- <=> [Al(OH)4]-}$